# Getting all unique combinations in python

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to figure out how to get combinations of a list of lists based on one element.

So let's assume I have this list of lists

```
    [["blue", 1], ["blue", 3], ["red", 6], ["green", 5]]
```

How would I get these combinations in python:

```
    [["blue", 1], ["red", 6], ["green", 5]], [["blue", 3], ["red", 6], ["green", 5]]
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the help of [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
data = [["blue", 1], ["blue", 3], ["red", 6], ["green", 5]]
groups = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda item: item[0]):
    groups.append(list(g))
print(list(itertools.product(*groups)))
# [(['blue', 1], ['red', 6], ['green', 5]), (['blue', 3], ['red', 6], ['green', 5])]

# just for understanding how it works:
print(groups)
# [[['blue', 1], ['blue', 3]], [['red', 6]], [['green', 5]]]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I am looking for!